# Зависимости статических библиотек

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Разработка и сборка ведётся средствами visual studio.
Есть следующая структура проектов

```
executable.exe
|-static_library1.lib
  |-kernel32.lib
  |-User32.lib
|-static_library2.lib
  |-Shell32.lib
  |-Shlwapi.lib
```

Есть необходимость как-то автоматизировать подключение зависимостей статической библиотеки к исполняемому файлу при линковке

Известный способ 1

```
#pragma comment(lib, ...)
```

Известный способ 2

Для проекта static_library прописать зависимости в

```
Properties->Librarian->General->Additional Dependencies
```

В дальнейшем подключать библиотеку через Project->References c опцией Link Library Dependencies = true

Известный способ 3

Вручную прописывать зависимости в свойствах проекта executable.exe

Существуют ли еще какие-либо способы автоматизации подключения зависимостей статических библиотек к исполняемым файлам?

Comment: А чем не угодили эти три способа?

Comment: Вдруг есть что-то еще, более удобное

Comment: Я бы советовал отказаться от проектов VS в сторону CMake или чего-то подобного. Тогда вопрос даже стоять не будет, потому что там будет какой-то свой один способ это делать (`#pragma` не считаю, потому что на других компиляторах не работает).